Latex in R markdown formatting table below my plot, not next to it
I am trying to format an R markdown file so that I have a table to the right of my created plot. Below is the code in my .Rmd file and a picture of what that code produces.

---
title: "test"
output: 
  pdf_document:
keep_tex: false
date: "2024-09-06"


header-includes:
  \usepackage{booktabs}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
```

```{=tex}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\end{minipage}
```

```{r plp, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.width=4,fig.height=3, fig.align='left'}
plot(cars)
data <- head(mtcars)

data %>% 
  kable(format = 'latex',linesep='',valign = 't', label = 'Cars', escape = FALSE, booktabs = TRUE
  ) %>% kable_styling(latex_options = "HOLD_position", position = "center")
```


In your picture, it looks like the table is too wide to fit beside the picture.  Can you make both of them smaller?
